# Python factors of a number

Tags: python

Prompt the user to input a number. Print out all factors of that number.

```
number = (input("Enter a number: "))

string = ""

for i in range(2, int(number)):

    if int(number) / i == 0:

        string = string + str(i)

print(string)
```

Why is this not returning anything?

Comment: The only value for which `int(number) / i == 0` will be `True` is if `int(number)` is zero.  You want remainder (`%`), not division (`/`).  Also, accumulating the factors in a string with no separation will produce ambiguous values once you reach 2 digits.

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace `if int(number) / i == 0:` with `if int(number) % i == 0:`, as you're getting the quotient, not the remainder

Comment: `string = string + ' ' +  + str(i) ` to insert spaces. but ideally you'd like to store the numbers in a list using `list_name.append(str(number))`, and use ` ' '.join(list_name)` to get the final string. This will help you manage it better

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
string = ' '.join([str(i) for i in range(2, number + 1) if number % i == 0])

print(string)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'join' is not defined

Comment: can you share the line of code where you used `join`

Comment: Was attempting to use with a string lol. Fixed it with using a list. Thanks